# "You cannot edit your mailing address": Does that mean that the USCIS is actively working on my N-400 online application and is likely to decide soon?

Tags: usa, citizenship

I read in my [USCIS profile](https://my.uscis.gov/account/applicant/profile), regarding my N-400 online application:

> You cannot edit your mailing address or physical address during this part of the adjudication process.

Does that mean that the USCIS is actively working on my N-400 online application and is likely to decide soon, or is just a standard message for any N-400 online application that is present all the time?

I read contradicting information online.

---

[image]